# Counting lines in a list

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a list of objects and colors; each object has a color. I want to create a query that will count how many objects I have of each color.

What function should I use?

Comment: Have you tried anything for yourself? What problems did you have? What is your input data and what output data do you need? From your brief description I would assume you want a count and a distinct but, *shrug*.

Comment: provide some more information brother

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might write a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(color) AS cnt, color FROM YourTable
GROUP BY color
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this without writing code, only using MS Access query builder.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Color, Count(Objects) 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Color
```